# How should I store linked list type data for website?

Tags: mysql, database-design, linked-list

I am thinking of having a top 7 list of items.
So, linked lists pop in my head because the new high ranking item will be added, or promoted from lower rank, to push down the lower ranking items by one step. The way I need it be.
I would just need to access the top 7 (a chosen number) of object according to the ranks. 
How should I store it in a database? Or should I store it in file storage? I could just add some item or write cut/paste type codes for the already ranked item, but unfortunately that's not how my db (MYSQL) works. So, any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just store the data in your database and have a column for score or rank or whatever the scoring criteria is. Then if you want the top 7 you could simply create a view. No need to store the data a second time. Not sure why you need a linked list here, it is just a result set with 7 rows in a certain order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the UI for adding a "new number 3".  This implies bumping everything 3 and greater by one.

So... You have a column that is the rank.  The SQL is

```
UPDATE MyList SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE rank >= 3;
INSERT INTO MyList (rank, ...)
    VALUES (3, ...);
```

Getting the top 7:

```
SELECT * FROM MyList WHERE rank <= 7 ORDER BY rank;
```

To "move" the current rank 12 item to rank 5, there are many approaches.  Here is one:

```
UPDATE MyList SET rank = -1 WHERE rank = 12;
UPDATE MyList SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE rank BETWEEN 5 AND 12;
UPDATE MyList SET rank = 5 WHERE rank = -1;
```